# Amazon S3 Upload Lag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, lag

I recently started hosting a site on S3, and I've been having issues with lag when uploading files to buckets. By lag, I mean 24 hours. Any idea what's wrong? I followed AWS' [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html) to hosting a static website. From some research, it may have something to do with Cloudfront not working properly?

P.S. I'm new to AWS and website-hosting in general.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say that this is due to 'cache' times for s3/cloudfront.
if you upload a file with a brand new filename then navigate to the URL does it appear immediately? 
The large benefit of something like S3 any other CDN really is that it is for data that isn't supposed to change
so its setup in such a way as to minimize browser requests for it where possible.

Try editing your site in a different enviroment and then uploading it to S3 once it is completed. it will save you a lot of frustration

Comment: Yup, new files with new names appear immediately, so it just might be due to cache times. Is there no workaround for this?

Comment: the simplest would be to add a question mark to the end of your url followed by random charecters that you change every time you update. 

Alternitively you could use the 'private browsing' mode in your web browser and close that off completely between tests... or clear your browser cache.

There are other methods (such as setting metadata for each file, which is a pain). And if you have cloudfront 'over the top' of your S3 then you also will have to go through and invalidate all of the Cloudfront cache's of your pages...